# How to add dynamic or changable files as assets in pkg nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe

I have added folders as assets to pkg for creating exe file.
The jsonfiles folder contains json files and I want to change the values of these json files and when changed should reflect in frontend.
The jsonfiles folder always displays the value which was present during compilation, I want to make these assets dynamic(i.e,json file changes should reflect on frontend)

```js
"pkg": {
    "assets":  [  "public/**/*", "jsonfiles/**/*" ],
    "targets": ["node14-win-x64" ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the dynamic files as assets, I added the files which are changing in a separate folder and made requests to those file for the data. Once the assets are converted to .exe file it is not changeable only required data we need can be got from other folders and displayed.